# Stripe managed account verification not working

Tags: php, api, stripe-connect

I'm using Stripe Connect to transfer funds to third party bank accounts.

I have created managed accounts in Stripe Connect and link bank account details to that account.

While verifying accounts using SSN numbers I'm getting the following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'Received unknown parameters: personal_id_number_provided, ssn_last_4_provided'

Code:

```
$account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve("acct_xxxxx");
$account->legal_entity->business_name = "Gowri Sankar";
$account->legal_entity->dob = array('day'=>05,'month'=>06,'year'=>1990);
$account->legal_entity->first_name = 'Gowri';
$account->legal_entity->last_name = 'Sankar';
$account->legal_entity->personal_address = array('city'=>'San Clemente','country'=>'US','line1'=>'100', 'line2'=>'Avenida Presidio', 'postal_code'=>'92672','state'=>'CA');

//These two lines gives error
$account->legal_entity->personal_id_number_provided = '8547';
$account->legal_entity->ssn_last_4_provided = true;


$account->legal_entity->type = 'individual';
$account->tos_acceptance->date = time();
$account->tos_acceptance->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$account->save();
```

I'm using Stripe PHP API.
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you figured this out by now, but those 2 parameters are not valid. The proper param should be `ssn_last_4`. Try running:

```
$account->legal_entity->ssn_last_4 = '8547';
```

Or perhaps (mostly for international clients):

```
$account->legal_entity->personal_id_number = '8547';
```

As per [the documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#update_account-legal_entity-ssn_last_4).